# Azure Synapse Authentication using Token Credentials

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-authentication

I am looking at running spark batch jobs on azure synapse. I am currently able to test the runs by using az cli for synapse.
On the production, I need to trigger these spark submissions via external application (prefect flows).

To submit the spark job, I am looking at using `azure synapse sdk` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-synapse/azure.mgmt.synapse.synapsemanagementclient?view=azure-python) with

How do I pass the `TokenCredential` as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-synapse/azure.mgmt.synapse.synapsemanagementclient?view=azure-python#constructor

Answer (score 1):

This was rather straightforward and I had overlooked the documentation.

The short code is below

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.synapse.spark import SparkClient
from azure.synapse.spark.models import SparkBatchJobOptions

def run(self, job_name: str, job_args):

   credential = ClientSecretCredential(self.tenant_id, self.client_id,self.client_secret)

   options = SparkBatchJobOptions.from_dict({
                "tags": None,
                "artifactId": None,
                "name": f"{job_name}",
                "file": f"{job_name}.py",
                "className": None,
                "args": job_args,
                "jars": [],
                "files": [],
                "archives": [],
                "conf": None,
                "driverMemory": "4g",
                "driverCores": 4,
                "executorMemory": "2g",
                "executorCores": 2,
                "numExecutors": 2,
            }

    })

    job = spark_client.spark_batch.create_spark_batch_job(options, detailed=False)
```